# Interpolating integer list by fixed decimal increments in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, floating-point

I want to create a list of interpolated decimals out of a list of integers.  The code I wrote gives me the result I'm looking for, but it seems very cumbersome:

```
integer_list = [288, 289, 290]
increment = 0.1
increment_list = [i * increment for i in range(10)]
interpolated_list = []

for integer in integer_list:
    for decimal in increment_list:
        interpolated_list.append(integer + decimal)

final_list = [number for number in interpolated_list if number <= integer_list[-1]]
```

There must be a more concise/efficient way to approach this problem.

Comment: I just learned about stackoverflow Code Review. This problem may have better suited for that venue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want concise, it's simple enough as a list comprehension:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
interp = [num + (dec / 10.) 
          for num in nums
          for dec in range(10)
          if num + (dec / 10.) <= max(nums)]
```

Up to you whether you find that clearer than the more explicit loops.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  And I've now learned how to write a multi-part list comprehension.